# Flickr API returns error 403

Tags: asp.net, flickr

In my ASP.NET application my FLickr feed has ceased working. I know that FLickr has gone to SSL only now but can find nowhere in the app to change http://www.flickr.com to https://www.flickr.com, I have changed all references in the FLickNet.XML file but still the same error..

Code as below

```
        Flickr fc = new Flickr("a5842f13a64533d3...", "1d0fc607e96...");

        String text = "";
        try
        {
            Photoset pss = fc.PhotosetsGetPhotos("721576080..."); // error 403 forbidden
```

Do I need a new FLickrNet.dll?
Is there another reference somehwhere I need to change?

Help please - cant find anything useful from Flickr

Comment: Any more detail on `403`? Are you using the [FlickrNet](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/) library? Seems that library was recently updated so do you have the latest release? Hth...

Comment: Thanks just downloading the new FlickrNet.dll fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the latest FickrNet.dll from http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/

Had to modify the code as Photoset class / type no longer used, but all now working